# Bootstrap Typeahead - Run updater function on input blur?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, input, blur, typeahead.js

I've attached typeahead to a series of input boxes. I'm also using the updater function to add an associated value to a hidden input when an item is selected from the typeahead list. My current code is below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="iwrapper" class="currentIng">
    <input type="hidden" name="ingredientId[]">
    <input type="text" name="ingredient[]" id="ingredient11" class="ingLeft ingName" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
var labels, mapped;
   $('.ingName').typeahead({
       source: function(query, process) {
           labels = [];
           mapped = {};
           var data = [{"iname":"Almond","ingid":"1","mabbr":"LOR"},{"iname":"Amaretto","ingid":"2","mabbr":"LOR"}, etc];
           $.each(data, function(i, ing) {
               var query_label = ing.iname + ' [' + ing.mabbr + ']';
               mapped[query_label] = ing;
               labels.push(query_label);
           });
           process(labels);
       },
       updater: function(query_label) {
           var ing = mapped[query_label];
           var input_label = ing.ingid; 
           $("ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu:visible").siblings("input[type='hidden']").val(input_label);
           return query_label;
       }
   };);
});
```

So, if a user starts typing Almond, **Almond [LOR]** will be displayed. If the user selects that entry in the list, the updater runs and a value of **1** will be added to the hidden input field. This is all working great.

**Problem:**
If a user types out the entire value and clicks away from the input, the hidden input value is not updated.

**Question:**
Is there any way I can alter my code to make updater run when the input field loses focus?

Here is a working example, with some minor edits for visibility:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/4/)

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net. Will likely need to store your data outslde of plugin initiaization code and do a manual search when input loses focus. Not 100% clear what you are trying to do in the `typeahead.dropdown-menu` as it won't be visible when input loses focus and instant somone types something new it is emptied and replaced with new elements

Comment: I updated my post with a link to a JSFiddle. The data is actually stored outside in a php variable. I just included part of it for readability.

Comment: have a solution that's work in progress using `blur` and searching data outside of bootstrap. Is workable, just haven't covered alll the various scenarios to test the value yet. See what you think http://jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/5/

Comment: This looks promising. The idea is to search the array for an exact match on blur. If an exact match is found, find the corresponding ingid of the match, and place that ingid in the "hidden" input field.

Comment: right... for now only doing visual display to debug. Can you run with this? Main issue right now is making sure all cases are covered with `if` and what to do when values  don't match. Be a lot easier using a more developer friendly autocmplete like `jQueryUI` which is easier to hook into

Comment: version with minor revision that updates hidden when search is positive. Likely need to reset it's value on error too   http://jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/7/  Can help further if you need it , or don't follow how blur methods i wrote are working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/8/ Gone about as far as I want on this for now..let me know if need assistance

Comment: This is great! One more quick question: is there a way to have it search the name + mabbr in brackets? Using your latest fiddle, if I type Almond [LOR] and click away, it returns 'no results'.

Comment: can fine tune tests in `var arr=$.grep`(likely easiest place to start) and check various versions of the value there, can also store both the `iname` value and the `query_label` value in data in the `bootsrap updater` and check both in the serach function. Fine tuning the various scenarios is defintiely a little tricky. Could also use regex to remove anything in `[]` when testing values.

Comment: [jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/12/](http://jsfiddle.net/NW6pc/12/) Works as desired. I can't thank you enough. Is there a way for me to send some kind of recognition your way for your help?

Comment: that's what this community is all about... helping out is also a learning experience...learn a lot here. I learned jQuery with no coding or prgramming background at all other than simple html/css by doing same thing in jQuery support forum

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap typeahead plugin has been supplanted in Bootstrap 3 by Twitter's [typeahead.js plugin](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/), which has richer functionality. Here's some demo code using that plugin:

```
function updater(event, suggestion) {
  console.log(suggestion.value);
}
$('.ingName').typeahead({local: ['abc', 'abd', 'def']});
// probably not necessary, if blur event is always fired
// $('.ingName').on('typeahead:selected', updater);
$('.ingName').on('blur', function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val(), datasets = $(this).data('ttView').datasets;
  for (var i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
    var dataset = datasets[i];
    dataset.getSuggestions(value, function(suggestions) {
      for (var j = 0; j < suggestions.length; j++) {
        if (suggestions[j].value === value) {
          updater(e, suggestions[j]);
          return;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This doesn't quite fit your data, as you have an array of objects instead of an array of strings. If your data is coming from a JSON file, then you can use the `prefetch` argument with a filter function; if the data is always local, then you can supply your own template/engine arguments if you want to continue to work with objects instead of strings. This code above at least includes the blur-handling code which you were asking about originally, I hope this plugin helps.